# Shemona Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred eighteen?

### ?שמונה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 318.

Lazy gematria may be worthy of discission, but perhaps not of a full-fledged answer.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred seventeen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: Azriel, Kol Yaakov, Divre Emuna, Shevet Gad, Ben Dorenu, Yishuv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Breishis 14:14 וַיִּשְׁמַע אַבְרָם, כִּי נִשְׁבָּה אָחִיו; וַיָּרֶק אֶת-חֲנִיכָיו יְלִידֵי בֵיתוֹ, שְׁמֹנָה עָשָׂר וּשְׁלֹשׁ מֵאוֹת, וַיִּרְדֹּף, עַד-דָּן, Avraham took 318 men with him to fight. Rashi says that it was only Eliezer and 318 is the Gematria of Eliezers name. רבותינו אמרו אליעזר לבדו היה, והוא מנין גימטריא של שמו

Comment: I can't believe I had to wait a whole 18 minutes for you to come up with this answer. You're losing your edge!

Comment: Bummer.  I've been waiting for this one to come up because I actually knew an answer to contribute (granted, so does everybody else, but it's unusual for me), but you beat me to it. :-(

Comment: See also http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14374&pgnum=13